# Python Tkinter Screen Snap

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way in that I could make a Tkinter window snap to the screen when it touches it, much like how Skype works when you drag it to a corner. I would like to try and achieve this with an option to turn it off in my future programs.

Edit: I decided it would be best to include some pictures to show what I meant.
[Skype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB69A.gif)

The same kind of "stick" can be obserevd in Paint.Net.
[Paint.Net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uECfK.gif)

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the behavior you seek to achieve? What does "snap to the screen when it touches" it mean? I just tried with skype, and it behaves like a normal app. (on OSX)

Comment: For me the windows snap in the same way as any normal window, unless they are set to be non-resizable with `root.resizable(False, False)`.

Comment: @Siwel I mean how when it touches any part of the outer screen, I kind of...connects to it. I would like to achieve this in my programs. I don't really know how I could explain it better...as I have no idea what it's called.

Comment: This functionality is typically implemented outside of the application, by the window manager. Are you sure that your window manager does this for other windows but doesn't do it for yours? Or are you asking how to do this on a system that doesn't natively support this feature? Also, are you wanting this "snap" feature to work when you drag the window or only when the app first starts up?

Comment: I am trying to implement this feature to work on my Windows programs. Naturally, Windows doesn't have a screen snap feature (I think). I would like it to always be able to snap to the sides of the screen when it touches the sides; much like my favorite example for this, Skype.

Answer (score 0):

```
root = Tk()
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
```

did you tried adding this to your code?

> I mean how when it touches any part of the outer screen, I kind
>   of...connects to it.

I use it in my code and it works just the way you mentioned

Comment: I think the OP wants this to happen as the window is dragged, not necessarily at start-up.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for your insight. I see that OP still hasn't mentioned it yet.

Comment: @DhruvJ Unfortunately, I do not mean for it to stretch to the screen size. Thank you for taking the time to ask, but I mean for it to attach to the side of the screen when it touches it slightly (Not for it to stretch to the size of half the screen).

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for your time, but as I have written in the reply to DhruvJ, this is still not what I mean, if there was a way to show you what I mean, I would, but recently, my desktop fan has cracked so I need to get a new one; and upgrade it a little.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is create a binding on the root window for the `<Configure>` event. This event fires when the root window changes in certain ways, including when the window moves. As the user drags the window, this event will fire many times. It will also fire when the user resizes the window, FWIW.

In the binding you can determine the current location of the window, and you can also get the screen dimensions. It's then a matter of comparing the window location to the screen dimensions to determine if the window should "snap".

If the window should "snap", you can use `after` to schedule the window to be moved after a short delay (so that it doesn't snap immediately, in case the user moved it all the way to an edge and then moves it back). You can then use the `geometry` method on the root window to place it against the edge, and/or resize it to fill the appropriate side of the monitor.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll have a go at this next time I'm doing some coding. Thanks for not just giving me the code c: